# HTML5 cache manifest index.html not loading linked files

Tags: html, caching, indexing, manifest

I am using a manifest file to cache my files. Between these files some are the index.html and some javascript libs.

After I tested my webpage , the files are successfully cached (i validated this with the web inspector), however when I open the page again the non-cached linked resources are not receiving response.

The link URL is ok because I can use the "copy link URL" option and paste the url in another browser tab and receive the response. But in my web page i am not receiving anything.

I tried using NETWORK: *  with the same result.

Is this because the index.html shouldn't be cached if it has non-cached resources linked?

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue in both Firefox and Chrome. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Could be an issue if you are trying to get your resources with https? http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=78859&q=manifest%20loading&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: @Joelmob, thanks but in my case there weren't any https requests. :(

Answer (score 0):

The Fallback Header has to be on it's own line, like so:

```
NETWORK:
*
```

(new line after the colon).

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the same template for the index.html and the uncached resources or including the  entry somehow in those? 
In that case you got the master entry for every page you don't want to be cached: every page that includes the manifest entry will became cached.